# How to initialize FindsBy in page factory when the Object IDs are dynamic

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I have this code for my IDs:

```
public int counter = 0;
public void AddClick(){
counter = counter + 1;
 driver.FindElement(By.Id(String.Format("btnAdd{0}_btnAddExpense", counter))).Click();
 Console.WriteLine("I am clicked {0} times!", counter);
}
```

How do I declare this in my FindsBy? Apparently, this doesn't work:

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "(String.Format("btnAdd{0}_btnAddExpense", counter")]
 public IWebElement contactBox { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the way you're identifying the elements from `Id` to `Xpath`.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Xpath, Using = "your_xpath_here")] public IWebElement contactBox { get; set; }
```

And to give you a short explanation of why it's not working, it's because the `Using=""` is accepting a constant value and you have a variable inside.

In order to do it using a variable in your `id`, `xpath` or something else you could create a property method of type `By` or `IWebElement` depending on what you need to do afterwards (although a `By` is preferred because you can use it a parameter in your `WebDriverWait`s):
For `By`;

```
public By ContactBoxBy(string counter)
{
    get {return By.Id("btnAdd{0}_btnAddExpense" + counter);}
}
```

For `IWebElement`:

```
public IWebElement ContactBox
{
    get {return driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnAdd{0}_btnAddExpense" + counter));}
}
```

This way you no longer need the `[FindsBy]` attribute.

Usage:

If you want to enter text in your contact box you will do:

```
driver.FindElement(ContactBoxBy(counter)).SendKeys("text to be inserted");
```

or directly using the `IWebElement`:

```
ContactBox.SendKeys("text to be inserted");
```

Comment: I am very new to the concept of page object model and automation scripting itself, so apologies for the basic question. How would I initialize the By ContactBoxBy in the FindsBy part?

Comment: By using the property methods you no longer need to have the `[FindsBy]` attribute.

Comment: so when I use the property methods and in order for the counter to increment, should it be like this: public By ContactBoxBy(string counter)
{  counter = counter + 1;
    get {return By.Id("btnAdd{0}_btnAddExpense" + counter);}
}

Comment: It's quite a bad idea to use a counter for the dynamic id. If you want to go using `[FindsBy]` attribute then change to identify your element using xpath.

Comment: right, though i couldn't think of another way to handle the dynamic ID that we are using. The btnAdd{0} has btnAdd1, btdnAdd2 and so forth that is why I used a counter.

Comment: Thanks @Cosmin for the awesome answer, I appreciate it!